# French stock giving monthly dividend?

Tags: stocks, dividends, france

Is there any french stocks or ETF that gives monthly or quarterly dividends? For example, US stocks such as Realty Income (O) gives monthly dividends. As far as I know, all french stocks give yearly divisends but I am curious to know if there is any stock listed on Paris Euronext gives monthly or quarterly dividends.

Comment: You'll probably need to look into bonds ETF's. Example: [VEMT](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-usd-emerging-markets-government-bond-ucits-etf-usd-distributing/distributions) this one should be available to buy on Euronext Paris and gives monthly dividends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://revenusetdividendes.com/liste-actions-toucher-dividendes-bourse/, no french stock gives a monthly dividend:

> Malheureusement, il n’existe pas d’actions à dividendes mensuels en France.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=en&text=Malheureusement%2C%20il%20n%E2%80%99existe%20pas%20d%E2%80%99actions%20%C3%A0%20dividendes%20mensuels%20en%20France.):

> Unfortunately, there are no monthly dividend shares in France.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution schedule of ETFs depends on the stocks themselves. For example, if most of the S&P 500 constituents are on quarterly schedule, then the S&P 500 ETFs would be on quarterly schedule. If real estate rent is monthly, then the real estate ETF would be monthly.

It would be sub-optimal if your selections are limited to a certain type of ETF that has monthly distribution.

It is best to compare Total Return (Price + Dividend) over the year after personal tax, then "Self-create" Dividend by selling tiny amount of shares each month.

See Dividend Irrelevance Theory.

Comment: I cannot sell the stock for 5 years once I keep it for a number of reasons...thanks for your advice but the theory that you introduced is irrelevant to me